# Map view not working in tabhost

Tags: android

I am new android developer. I have created a mapview application. When i use `MapView` in `main.xml` layout then it works. But when I use `MapView` in a `TabHost` element named `banklocation.xml` layout then the maps does not show.

Comment: Can You add some more details/snippets?